# VS2012 and SQL Server Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2008-express

I learnt that VS2012 comes with a version of SQL Server Express named LocalDb that works a little bit different from the usual SQL Server Express, the latter one works as a service.

What if I was interested in using the database as a service, can I have both installed, the new one that comes with VS2012 and SQL Server Express 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this slightly wrong. It doesn't come with a local database, it comes with a built in GUI to access SQL Server (what ever version). You can use any database you like (multiple databases) and connect to the SQL Server using the Visual Studio version of SSMS.

So, yes, you can install multiple versions of SQL Server on your machine. I currently have 2005 express, 2008 developer edition, 2012 developer edition and express.

Comment: I'm starting a project and I don't know exactly what I'll need in the future, I'm trying to figure out my preferred environment, I know that it has a Visual Studio (2012 for now), Sql Server Express (I don't know why the name change), Silverlight, Azure, Wpf, etc.. and development for small businesses.  Knowing that, do you think that the current Sql Server 2012 Express will suffice?

Comment: @Rafael It is too hard to answer, but, if you're just starting then yes. I've only had to use SQL SERVER for large enterprise jobs with work. For my own websites and software projects, I use SQL express and it's fine. All of these things are confusing when you start, my advice is to start small and don't use the biggest and most powerful; typically they exist to solve a problem but can come with their own problems. I suggest start with Sql Server Express and only if it doesn't do something then think about moving, and Google SQL Server Express Limitations to understand it better.

Comment: Hi dave. When you say SQL Server Express, are you referring to SQL Server Express 2008 or the SQL Server Local DB that ships with VS2012?. I'm trying to standardize the development towards VS2012 as my dev env, but with respect to Silverlight projects, I think (maybe I'm wrong) that SQL Server Express 2008 is a better option. Don't you think?

Comment: Remember, SQL typically is backward compatible, just not forward compatible. Personally, I'd install SQL Server 2012 on your machine and point your connections from within Visual Studio to that.